# Blank screen with release mode, app does not start. Working fine in debug mode

Tags: android, apk, release, signed

I just created my release candidate with Android Studio in release mode and generating a signed apk. Everything fine, but when I test it in my device or other devices, the app starts and just shows a blank screen. No login screen, nothing.

The logs of the release version doesn't say anything to me. It's the first time that happens to me after 4 years of app development. I don't really understand what's going on.

I've also tried the rolling back to the version that we have in Google Play Store, same happens. Debug working fine, Release signed not working.

I tried it with another computer and another phone, same issues.

I will appreciate any help, because I never felt that lost.

These are the logs

```
09-13 17:27:07.837 16977-16977/? I/applabs.sharif: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-13 17:27:07.918 16977-16977/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/applabs.sharif: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
09-13 17:27:08.052 16977-16977/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
09-13 17:27:08.080 16977-16977/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
09-13 17:27:08.096 16977-16977/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
09-13 17:27:08.138 16977-16977/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.6.1.23
09-13 17:27:08.151 16977-16977/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
09-13 17:27:08.168 16977-16977/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify E/com.facebook.internal.a: getAttributionIdentifiers should not be called from the main thread
09-13 17:27:08.178 16977-17019/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
09-13 17:27:08.276 16977-17002/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 12451
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app es.sharifyapplabs.sharify
09-13 17:27:18.273 16977-17014/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify W/Fabric: Could not call getAdvertisingIdInfo on com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient
09-13 17:27:18.274 16977-17014/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify W/Fabric: Could not call getId on com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info
09-13 17:27:28.333 16977-17014/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify W/Fabric: Could not call getAdvertisingIdInfo on com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient
09-13 17:27:28.334 16977-17014/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify W/Fabric: Could not call isLimitAdTrackingEnabled on com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info
09-13 17:27:28.658 16977-17006/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
09-13 17:27:29.907 16977-17006/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify W/CrashlyticsCore: Expected method missing: registerOnMeasurementEventListener
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: parameter type is null
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2060)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
        at com.crashlytics.android.c.u.a(DefaultAppMeasurementEventListenerRegistrar.java:89)
        at com.crashlytics.android.c.u.a(DefaultAppMeasurementEventListenerRegistrar.java:54)
        at com.crashlytics.android.c.k.a(CrashlyticsController.java:1574)
        at com.crashlytics.android.c.l.d(CrashlyticsCore.java:320)
        at com.crashlytics.android.c.l.e(CrashlyticsCore.java:44)
        at c.a.a.a.h.a(InitializationTask.java:63)
        at c.a.a.a.h.a(InitializationTask.java:28)
        at c.a.a.a.a.c.a$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
09-13 17:27:38.083 16977-16996/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
09-13 17:28:38.101 16977-16996/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
09-13 17:30:08.126 16977-16996/es.sharifyapplabs.sharify E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Invalidate Cache/Restart Android Studio.

2) Refresh Build completely, Sign Apk & test!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. Basically Facebook messed up again.

Related to the dependency in gradle.

App getting stuck with E/com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers

Comment: enable debugging in release mode and then select build variant as release to debug release version

Comment: @diego-gaspar could you give me some more info about what exactly was Facebook messing up? I am having the same issue and I am completely lost

Comment: @moyo downgrade facebook sdk version in Gradle file